# How do I create table using row & col index in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

My JSON looks like this:-

```
{
"tblDetails": [{
    "id": 1,
    "rowIndex": 1,
    "colIndex": 1
}, 
{
    "id": 2,
    "rowIndex": 1,
    "colIndex": 2
}, 
{
    "id": 3,
    "rowIndex": 1,
    "colIndex": 4
}, 
{
    "id": 4,
    "rowIndex": 1,
    "colIndex": 6
}
]}
```

And HTML Structure as below:-

```
<table id="tblLayout"><tbody> </tbody></table>
```

I am using jQuery ajax to fetch JSON data.

```
 $.ajax(
 { 
   url : "/hello/data.json",
   type: "GET",
   success: function(data)
   {
       var tbl  = data.tblDetails;
       tbl.forEach(item)
       {
       var html = item.id;
       $('#tblLayout> tbody > tr:eq('+(item.rowIndex)+') td:eq('+(item.colIndex)+')').append(html);
       }

   },
   error:function(e)
   {

   }
 })
```

Now how do I append the html at the specified row-col in the table tblLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the exact solution but this is what I did for the required layout.

I replaced table with ul as:-

```
<ul id="tblLayout"></ul>
```

jQuery ajax

```
$.ajax(
{ 
url : "/hello/data.json",
type: "GET",
success: function(data)
{
   var tbl  = data.tblDetails;
   tbl.forEach(item)
   {
   var html ="<li class='seat style='position:absolute;top:" + (item.rowIndex * 50) + "px;left:" + (item.colIndex * 50) + "px;'>" + item.id+ "</li>";

   $('#tblLayout>).append(html);

   }
   },
  error:function(e)
  {

  }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You get data from "data.json" in JSON format. Try this:

```
  $.ajax({
url: "data.json",
type: "GET",
success: function (data) {
  var tbl = JSON.parse(data).tblDetails;
  $.each(tbl, function (k, v) {
    var html = v.id;
    $('#tblLayout> tbody > tr:eq(' + (v.rowIndex) + ') td:eq(' + (v.colIndex) + ')').append(html);
  });

},
error: function (e) {

}
```

});

Comment: It would be perfect if you could post the example into an (JSFiddle)[https://jsfiddle.net] to show it working

Comment: @Igor Danylov... I checked with this...but it doesn't rendered

Comment: @Chetan Are you want rewrite cell or add "id" to exists text?

Comment: @IgorDanylov.. on page load or intially all I have is empty table `<table id='tblLayout'> </table>`

Comment: @IgorDanylov..What you think about my ans

Comment: @Chetan..jQuery doesn't have method to build table. You can build HTML like "<tr><td>content</td></tr>" use loops. Unfortunately I don't understand your json structure.